# What is maximum capacity of SD Card which PSP Street E1004 supports?

Tags: technical-issues, psp

I bought a few days ago PSP Street E1004. I realize that it is quite a poor version of Sony's portable console, but I read specifications and most of the things that were removed in it are unnecessary for me (except Wi-Fi, but I can realize how bad it will be working in current times).

I bought a console with an SD card with a capacity of 8GB. I thought that it will be sufficient for my requirements, but I quite fast saw that it would be great to have a few gigabytes of space more.

So my question is - how big an SD card can I apply into my PSP, to be sure that it will be compatibly with it and - what's the most important - will be working perfectly? I thought about 64GB, but I am not sure, that such a big capacity will be working with that so old device.

Also, there is a second question - do various versions of PSP have different limits of external memory size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not receive any answer, so I just bought a 64GB SD Card and plug it into PSP (in MSPro Duo converter) and it works fine, so the answer is: Yes, it works.